# Who will be able to see the result of moderator agreement accept/reject decision?

Tags: support, moderators, localization

In traducir I found the string like [this](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14799):

> Moderator accepted a previous version of the moderator agreement but has not accepted the current version.

I'm curious who will responsible to see this type of string? If it's only staff, should we ever need allowing to translate it from English?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the moderator dashboard, if a moderator has not accepted the moderator agreement, a red asterisk shows up next to their name, visible to other moderators on the site. If you roll over that asterisk, the string "This user has not yet accepted the moderator agreement" shows up.

While the moderator agreement change happened between my stepping down and stepping back up, I presume that the same effect happens when a change to the mod agreement happens that requires re-acceptance. A similar red asterisk or whatever it is will show up, visible to staff and other moderators, indicating that this moderator has not yet accepted the new version of the agreement.

It's a very specialized string that is only visible very rarely and to only a few people, but I don't think it *hurts* to have it translated.

Comment: [Here are some of the relevant strings in Traducir (for Russian)](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=agreement) – and yeah, I think even if it's a string only shown to a few folks/in rare cases, if it's a string like this that *is* translatable, it's worth translating it (assuming it does actually appear on the site).